# Responsive CSS Horizontal Scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to add a horizontal scroll onto a page so that when you scroll vertically, the page scrolls horizontally. I found a piece of code that can do this which is entirely CSS based however it doesn't seem to be responsive. I found this on CodePen.

Is there any way in which this code can be transformed into the page being responsive?

I've attached the code below.

```css
#container {
  margin-top: -15px;
}

#container .box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#container .box>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 96px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 2.6%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  line-height: .7;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background-color: #999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
}

#container2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.one {
  background-color: #45CCFF;
}

.two {
  background-color: #49E83E;
}

.three {
  background-color: #EDDE05;
}

.four {
  background-color: #E84B30;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container2">

    <div class="box one">
      <div class="full">
        <img class="desktop" src="public/images/lookbook/4.jpg" alt="Header" />
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="box two">
      <div>2</div>
    </div>


    <div class="box three">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>


    <div class="box four">
      <div>Last</div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone has any idea - please let me know!

Comment: width:100vw; height:100vh means the width and height always match the maximum of the screen its on. So I am not quite sure what's the issue? Perhaps uncomment them lines?

Comment: @DanielVickers thanks for replying - I want it so that when you resize the screen, the image stays the full width of the screen without showing the blue background, Have tried uncommenting them lines but it doesn't keep the image at full width and still shows the blue background

Comment: make the image display:block and give it a width of 100%

Comment: @hannah from your description it seems like you want the image to stretch along the full scroll. This means the image would be distorted, to remedy this you would need to set the image as a background image and set the size to cover with no-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I took the initiative to remove all those ugly white spaces and scroll bars, plus what you asked for: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/vjKJzo)

```
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    width: calc(100vh + 17px);
    height: 100vw;
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    transform-origin: top left;
    background-color: #999;
    position: absolute;
}

#container2 {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
}

 #container .box {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
} 

 #container .box > div {
    font-size: 96px;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0.9;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.full {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.desktop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
}

.one {background-color: #45CCFF;}
.two {background-color: #49E83E;}
.three {background-color: #EDDE05;}
.four {background-color: #E84B30;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you want, use the image as a background instead. This allows it to cover the div completely as you'd like it to. Whilst also being responsive.

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#container .box {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}

#container .box>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 96px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px;
  line-height: .7;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background-color: #999;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
}

#container2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}

.one {
  background-color: #45CCFF;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1022454/pexels-photo-1022454.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);

}

.two {
  background-color: #49E83E;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1023949/pexels-photo-1023949.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
}

.three {
  background-color: #EDDE05;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/963071/pexels-photo-963071.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
}

.four {
  background-color: #E84B30;
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1022928/pexels-photo-1022928.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container2">
    <div class="box one">
      <div class="full">
        <div>1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box two">
      <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box three">
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box four">
      <div>Last</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```